# Show database on bootstrap modal with Ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm new at Laravel and ajax, I want to show database from mysql to Bootstrap modal, follow [this](https://justcode.me/php/how-to-load-mysql-data-in-bootstrap-modal-body-using-ajax/)

I use Laravel framework, this is the table

```
<tbody>
        <?php
            $result = DB::select('SELECT * FROM thongtinlodat');

            foreach ($result as $key) {
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$key->TenNhaDauTu.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$key->SoNhaDauTu.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$key->NgayCapNDT.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$key->NoiCapNDT.'</td>';
                    echo '<td>
                            <a class="btn btn-small btn-primary"
                               data-toggle="modal"
                               data-target="#exampleModal"
                               id="getUser"
                               data-whatever="'.$key->ID.' ">VIEW</a>
                         </td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        ?>
</tbody>
```

Modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">View info</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="dash">
             <!-- Content goes in here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is javascript with ajax

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
          var recipient = button.data('whatever'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
          var modal = $(this);
          var id = recipient;
          var dataString = 'id=' + recipient;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "editdata",
                data: dataString,
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    modal.find('.dash').html(data);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });  
    });
```

File editdata.php, get id from ajax and select data from mysql

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $members = DB::table('thongtinlodat')
                ->where('ID', $id)
                ->first();
?>
```

In the routes, how can I get id to insert to the URL, like this `Route::get('/editdata{?id=}', 'adminController@test');`?
Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 1):

> In the routes, how can I get id to insert to the URL?

#### Like this:

```
Route::get('my/route/{arg1}', 'MyController@show')->where('arg1', '[0-9]+');
```

And in your controller:

```
public function show(arg1){...}
```

The "where" clause allows you to tell the route what to expect as an argument. For example in the lone above, the arg1 must be positive integer.

Looking at your code, I can only recommend you to look at laravel doc :). It's really well written and you will see how to improve your code. 
More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters